# Switch to make MCU pin float

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, switches, floating-pin

I have an application where I need to make a ADC input pin (0-1V) float controlled by GPIO (any connect it in other cases to its input obviously).

I was considering a transistor in-line with the ADC input but that does not seem feasible since neither collector nor emitter have a defined voltage.

Does there exist a solution apart from a mechanical relay?

Comment: Seems like an analog switch IC might work, but I'm a little curious as to your application needing it to float completely. Source of randomness? By definition adding any circuit onto there is going to change how that pin "floats" around.

Comment: @KrunalDesai The MCU needs the pin floating for some internal calibration. Once that is done, I am free to use it.

Comment: What micro are you using?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Could you please give me some idea on what part of the question is unclear?

Answer (score 2):

An "Analog Switch" (a.k.a Bilateral Switch) would do the job. Examples include the [CD4016B](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4016b.pdf).

They are essentially two MOSFETs connected drain to source to allow bidirectional current flow. When turned off, they become essentially a very high resistance to whatever voltage the ADC output is.

For the CD4016B above, the off-state leakage current is about 1μA which at 1V for example corresponds to around 1MΩ. Whether or not that is enough isolation depends on how much isolation you require for your application. You can probably find "Solid State Relays" with higher isolation, but they will probably be more expensive too.

You also have to make sure the load is large enough that the analogue signal doesn't get distorted too much by the switch. For the CD4016B this is somewhere in the ~10kΩ region.

Answer (score 1):

> Neither collector nor emitter have a defined voltage

That is not quite true: you told us that the signal to monitor is in the range 0-1V. So, we know something.

Now, if you put a NPN, with the emitter towards the signal source, and its collector towards the ADC input pin, a large resistor (like 100k) between the base and the control GPIO, you have your problem solved. For this to work, the base voltage needs to be greater than `1V (max signal voltage) + Vbe (0.7V)`, so 3.3V from the control GPIO would be all right. When the control voltage is 0, the ADC input is high impedance. Note that the base resistor value must be much greater than the signal source impedance, or it will act as a voltage divider and you'll loose accuracy.

This is an uncommon configuration of the NPN, because the current can flow either from the collector to the emitter, or in the opposite direction, but it works.

This could work also with MOSFET, but the body diode will have some side effects, so you'd need to put two back-to-back.

The analog switch is another completely different solution, but it has already been explained.

Comment: I did not realise that current was allowed to flow in the "wrong" direction in transistors. I was secretly hoping for a solution like this, hence me specifying 0-1V... Many thanks.